# React app Clock having an error in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

Just a newbie question I wonder what should I do to make work the useEffect
I am getting error on the useEffect

Line 15:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'refreshClock'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

```
import  { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const { time, setTime } = useState(new Date());

  function refreshClock() {
    setTime(new Date());
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const timerID = setInterval(refreshClock, 1000);
    return function cleanup() {
      clearInterval(timerID);
    };
  }, []);

  return <span>Time : {time.toLocaleTimeString()}</span>;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is due to the fact that you make use of `refreshClock` function inside `useEffect()` without declaring it in the dependency array.

Additionally you would get another warning regarding `setTime`, here you can make use of `useCallback()` and declare `setTime` inside its own dependency array.

```
function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date());

  const refreshClock = React.useCallback(() => {
    setTime(new Date());
  }, [setTime]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timerID = setInterval(refreshClock, 1000);
    return function cleanup() {
      clearInterval(timerID);
    };
  }, [refreshClock]);

  return <span>Time : {time.toLocaleTimeString()}</span>;
}
```

Comment: That's great haven't encounter callback code yet thanks for the answer appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue about missing dependencies in `useEffect()` is just a warning and not the the main reason why the above code doesn't work. Actually the `useState()` has not been destructured correctly. You need to destrucuture into an array (please notice the `[]` instead of `{}` on `useState()` line):

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date());

  useEffect(() => {
    function refreshClock() {
      setTime(new Date());
    }
    const timerID = setInterval(refreshClock, 1000);
    return function cleanup() {
      clearInterval(timerID);
    };
  }, [setTime]);

  return <span>Time : {time.toLocaleTimeString()}</span>;
}

export default App;
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-cherry-5h5dnj?file=/src/App.js)

This is because `useState()` returns an array. `{}` notation is used to destructure an object.

As a side note it is a good idea to include the function within `useEffect` as shown above. Please read more about it here: https://reacttraining.com/blog/when-to-use-functions-in-hooks-dependency-array/

Comment: That's why doesn't display on my end guess I'm not really focus on the bracket but, Thanks on the suggestion I'll read it carefully